# Android Jetpack: RecyclerView is not updating when LiveData is set

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-livedata

So I have a simple implementation to display a list of users in a `RecyclerView`, and the list is queried in a `ViewModel` as [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData).

The problem is that the UI is not updated to show the latest list - called `users` - even when the list is observed. I just set up a list of demo users for now.

Here's my ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val demoData = listOf(
            User(userName = "Bob", favoriteColor = "Green"),
            User(userName = "Jim", favoriteColor = "Red"),
            User(userName = "Park", favoriteColor = "Blue"),
            User(userName = "Tom", favoriteColor = "Yellow"),
            User(userName = "Lee", favoriteColor = "Black"),
            User(userName = "Xiu", favoriteColor = "Gray")
    )

    private val _users = MutableLiveData<List<User>>()
    val users: LiveData<List<User>>
        get() = _users

    init {
        _users.value = listOf()
    }

    fun loadUsers() {
        _users.value = demoData.toMutableList().apply { shuffle() }
    }
}
```

And my ViewModel's attached Fragment:

```
// ...

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.users.observe(this, Observer {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })

    mAdapter = UsersAdapter(viewModel.users.value!!)

    mainRV = view?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_main)?.apply {
        adapter = mAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view?.context)
    }

    viewModel.loadUsers()
}
```

P.S. the `UsersAdapter` is a usual `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

I have made sure to call `setValue` on my users list to call the Observer, thus I am not sure what is missing here. Is my adapter wrongly setup?

Comment: It would help to see at least the "binding" part of your adapter. Also you don't need to call apply{ }, you can call shuffle() directly. Normally new list is passed to adapter in the observer callback.

Comment: Because the list doesn't mutate in place. You `getValue` the first value and that's it. You should set the new list in your `observe` method to your adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun loadUsers() {
    _users.value = demoData.toMutableList().apply { shuffle() }
}
```

`toMutableList()` creates a new list with the data, see the source code:

```
public fun <T> Collection<T>.toMutableList(): MutableList<T> {
    return ArrayList(this)
}
```

So instead of getting the initial value and never updating your adapter, you should update the list in the adapter and show that.

```
viewModel.users.observe(this, Observer { users ->
    mAdapter.updateData(users)
})
```

Where if you are not [using `ListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter), then you can define this method like this:

```
class MyAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>(
   private var list: List<User> = Collections.emptyList()
) {
    ...

    fun updateData(users: List<User>) {
        this.users = users
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

You can also use [`ListAdapter` and `submitList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter) and you'll also get animations.